# Ligatures and umlauts in Sphinx search

Tags: sphinx

I have a list of names with ligatures and umlauts (using Sphinx). Try to search "Æther" give me a result. But i want to have an ability to search these names with replaced ligatures as "Aether" for example.

Can Sphinx do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

**umlauts**, can be dealt with directly by `charset_table` 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

Alas there is no easy way to just tell sphinx to index everything, needs an explicit charset_table setup to your own requirements. This is perhaps
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9312
the best starting point

**ligatures**, is more trickly because its not a one-to-one mapping. I think `regexp_filter`, would be the best way to deal with these
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-regexp-filter